# Worklight wlapp deployment SQL error for GADGETS table on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst

> Failed to deploy application 'xxxx.wlapp'. : Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'LAST_UPDATE_TIME' at row 1 {prepstmnt 24265963 INSERT INTO GADGETS (DISP_IN_GALLERY, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (Timestamp) 2013-05-25 17:21:49.806, (String) xxxxxxxx]} [code=0, state=22001]

is coming for all `.wlapp` uploads in Worklight console. This is a Worklight war on Tomcat 7 and MySQL 5.6.

It seems from the error that the `INSERT` statement is trying to insert a value of datatype `TIMESTAMP` into a column that is of type `datetime` [`LAST_UPDATE_TIME` in gadgets table].

Comment: Have you tried with a clean database?

Comment: Yes. I deleted the WRKLGHT table and recreated it using the ** create-worklight-mysql.sql ** shipped with Worklight Server. I believe that is the right way to clean up ?

Failed to deploy application 'jqmMultipageSite1-android-1.0.wlapp'. : Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'LAST_UPDATE_TIME' at row 1 {prepstmnt 1028454292 INSERT INTO GADGETS (DISP_IN_GALLERY, LAST_UPDATE_TIME, NAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=(int) 1, (Timestamp) 2013-05-26 15:34:53.463, (String) jqmMultipageSite1]} [code=0, state=22001]

Comment: I meant WRKLGHT Schema instance.

Comment: @IdanAdar Is there any issues with WL 5.0.6 ? Now I get SQL errors while uploading Android application using the application center shipped with the server.

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785075/worklight-appcenter-application-android-app-upload-sql-error[link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest in: [Worklight Appcenter Application Android App upload SQL Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785075/worklight-appcenter-application-android-app-upload-sql-error)

Since IBM Worklight does not support MySQL 5.6, please install MySQL 5.1 or 5.5 (do not forget to edit my.ini with the max_allowed_packet change), and see if deployment passes.

Comment: All the SQL issues resolved with MYSQL version 5.5.31.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

- Locate the file my.ini belonging to your MySQL installation In it,
  find the section [mysqld]
- Under the section name, paste this: max_allowed_packet=500M if does
  not exist, Or if exist then increase the size by 500M.
- Under the section name, paste this: innodb_log_buffer_size=30M if
  does not exist, Or if exist then increase the size by 30M.
- Re-start the MySQL service
- Re-deploy the .wlapp files
- Deployment should now pass.