# Worklight Appcenter Application Android App upload SQL Error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to install IBMApplicationCenter.apk ( Appcenter application shipped with Worklight server for android ),using the Worklight ApplicationCenter console. This results in this SQL Error:

`Caused by: <openjpa-1.2.2-r422266:898935 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'CREATED' at row 1 {prepstmnt 428593325 INSERT INTO APPLICATION_MD (ACTIVE, APNS_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD, APNS_GATEWAY, CREATED, DESCRIPTION, IS_INSTALLER, LABEL, MANDATORY, OS, PKG, READY_PROD, RESOURCE_TYPE, UPDATED, VENDOR, VERSION, VERSION_NAME, VERSION_NUM, AUTHOR, ACL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [params=(String) Y, (String) , (String) , (Timestamp) 2013-05-28 11:37:28.433, (String) The compiled package file for the Android version of the Application..., (String) N, (String) IBM App Center, (String) N, (String) Android, (String) com.ibm.appcenter@Android, (String) N, (String) apk, (Timestamp) 2013-05-28 11:37:28.433, (String) , (String) 1, (String) 1.0, (double) 1.0000099998474121, (int) 2, (int) 2]} [code=0, state=22001]`

I had similar issues with the data type conversions and truncation while uploading the apps in Worklight Console. See this :

[worklight-wlapp-deployment-sql-error-for-gadgets-table-on-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749867/worklight-wlapp-deployment-sql-error-for-gadgets-table-on-mysql)

Make me wonder whether there are issues with the schemas that are shipped with the Worklight Enterprise installation. I have tried cleaning and re-creating the Appcenter schema.

Comment: I would even say it is the SAME issue, so no need for another question. Please tell me: what is the MySQL driver you are using?

Comment: I am using MYSQL driver V 5.6.11 . From the post below it looks like Worklight 5 isnt compatible with MYSQL 5.6.11 yet.? Do you agree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your other question, I conclude that you use MySQL.

Make sure you are not using MySQL 5.6 or later. There have been changes in date and timestamp behaviors between MySQL 5.5 and MySQL 5.6.

Worklight is compatible with MySQL 5.1 and 5.5. For details, see [IBM Worklight Application Center 5.0.6 System Requirements](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProductByComponent?deliverableId=C2E8EF801E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36&duComponent=Server_C2F301A01E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36#).

Comment: Yes I am using mySQL 5.6.11. So the mySQL version is an issue then ? (not good) . Do you know if there is a fix pack coming for Worklight for the same ?

Comment: Worklight currently does not support MySQL 5.6. We cannot comment on future releases whether it is yes or no.

Comment: All the SQL issues resolved with MYSQL version 5.5.31.
Cheers!!